# Cypress hljs is not defined

Tags: javascript, exception, cypress

I wrote a simple test to visit the site `https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/`

```
describe('My First Test Suite', () => {
   it("should navigate to the application", () => {
      cy.visit("https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/");
   });
})
```

But, I am getting this error :

```
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

  > hljs is not defined

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event
```

I understand that Cypress cannot do much here, but still looking for some pointers if there's some way to fix this so the page loads correctly? I don't have much of JS experience here.

Comment: I can run that without problem - is there something in your config that's unusual?

Comment: Perhaps it's an incomplete install - try removing `node_modules` folder and re-install everything.

Comment: @TesterDick : Did a fresh install, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The line that is *likely* (not definitely) to be causing your problem is

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

This adds library `hljs` to the page.

You can see the above script tag if you open `https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/` in a browser (not Cypress) and look at the Elements tab in devtools.

It's difficult to know why this script is blocked, because it works ok on my machine.

Try putting this URL `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js` in the browser also, may give you some clues.

Is there a firewall preventing you access to the above?

Comment: Somehow, the link opens okay in the Electron browser option but fails for the others.